# How to install Gnash SWF player in ubuntu?

Tags: flash, gnash

When I open cricinfo.com, there is a message "Additional plugins are required to display all the media on this page" in the left-top side of the webpage, and "install missing plugins" at the right-top. When I click on "install missing plugins", two plugings are listed,

1. Adobe Flash Player (installer)
2. Gnash SWF Player

I have installed by clicking on the first one, it is installed, but the problem remains same. On the other hand, I am not able to install
the second one. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Press the Windows Key on your keyboard, also known as the "Super".
Type the word "soft" without quotes and press enter.
After the Ubuntu software center has completed loading.
Type the word "gnash" without quotes and look at the screen.

There are two choices.  Unless you are using Kubuntu, don't install the one designed for KDE.